# Can I get a user's current ringtone/vibrate settings

Tags: android, notifications, ringtone

I'd like to alert the user when they are sent a message through our app. I do not want to arbitrarily create a ring or vibration.  If possible I would like to get a reference to their current ring setting and use that. How should I  access this from within my app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at [Android Audio Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager)

> It provides you access to volume and ringer control.

Choose from the constants that best describes your scenario.